# The property $xxx is not a valid price specification in Magento1.9.3.2

Tags: magento-1.9.3.2, google

[image: (The property 3,999 is not a valid price specification.)]

Can any one tell me please that how can i fix this issue.....

Comment: You must have edited price section. It produce error if you added braces before/after it. Post your price code line to check

Comment: yes i have removed the decimals like 499.00 to 499 from the code.

Comment: Ok. @userpk already provided you details you required.  If it still not fixed, put the code here so we can check.

Comment: hi i have changed here
app/code/core/Mage/Directory/Model/Currency.php
code-----

Comment: hi i have changed here
app/code/core/Mage/Directory/Model/Currency.php
code-----
 public function format($price, $options = array(), $includeContainer = true, $addBrackets = false)
    {
        return $this->formatPrecision($price, 2, $options, $includeContainer, $addBrackets);
    }
to
 public function format($price, $options = array(), $includeContainer = true, $addBrackets = false)
    {
        return $this->formatPrecision($price, 0, $options, $includeContainer, $addBrackets);
    }

now again changed 0 to 2 but same  error here.

http://awesomescreenshot.com/0b16bo3p0b

Comment: Did your try answer from @userpk ?

Comment: yes i have tried that solution but that not worked

Answer (score 1):

The Price you have specified is 3,999 where as google accepts it in simple number format.

**See Usage guidelines:**

- Use the priceCurrency property (with ISO 4217 codes e.g. "USD")
  instead of including ambiguous symbols such as '$' in the value.
- Use '.' (Unicode 'FULL STOP' (U+002E)) rather than ',' to indicate a
  decimal point. Avoid using these symbols as a readability separator.
- Note that both RDFa and Microdata syntax allow the use of a
  "content=" attribute for publishing simple machine-readable values
  alongside more human-friendly formatting.
- Use values from 0123456789 (Unicode 'DIGIT ZERO' (U+0030) to 'DIGIT
  NINE' (U+0039)) rather than superficially similiar Unicode symbols.

**You can try this**

```
<span itemprop="priceCurrency" content="INR">INR</span><span
      itemprop="price" content="3999.00">3,999.00</span>
```

For more reference view [here](http://schema.org/price)